# graphQL query with nested logical operators (and, or)

Tags: graphql, nested, logical-operators

I'm a total beginner in GraphQL. I just tryout some playgrounds and ideas.

But I'm interested in GraphQL and in using of logical operators in a nested way:

```js
query
{
  Transactions (
    where: {
      or: [
        and: [
          {apiTransactionId: {eq: "AAAAA"}},
          {customerFirstName: {eq: "Seth"}}
        ],
        and: [
          {apiTransactionId: {eq: "BBBBB"}},
          {customerFirstName: {eq: "Terry"}}
        ],
      ]
    }
  )
  {
    id,
    md5Hash
  }
}
```

It throws an error on the first "and: []", therefore on the second level. The error is "wrong syntax".

It looks like, the second level of logical operators is not valid.

Is there no way to combine OR- and AND- operators?

Maybe anytime I need a complex query like that.

Thanks for every info about it. :)

Comment: no general graphql specs for that ... all is implementation specific - unknown

Comment: @xadm:
Okay, then I have to add it on server side.
Or I try to use StrawberryShake for my C#.NET backend.
Alright, thank you.